Heat equation: initial condition given by measure concentrated on submanifold
I understand that the heat kernel $K_t(x,y)$ solves the heat equation with initial condition given by a delta distribution $\delta_y$. One can use this then to produce solutions for initial conditions given by nice functions, e.g. $L^2$, by convolution.
Is there a reference for how to solve the heat equation when the initial condition is given by, say, a measure supported on a submanifold? In the example above, the delta function is simply a measure supported on a point.
More generally, we could take the 2-dimensional torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ (think of it as the square $[0,1]^2$) and take a function, e.g. a harmonic $e^{inx}$, on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and embed it as one of the sides of the torus or as the diagonal. Can we find a function $u_t(x)$ satisfying the heat equation for $t>0$ that, inuitively starts to resemble the harmonic concentrated around the diagonal as $t \to 0$? Unfortunately, convolving with the heat kernel does not work, since the submanifold has measure $0$ (with the Lebesgue measure on the torus).
This question seems related.

A submanifold can be identified with a distribution, and it's just to take the convolution of the ordinary kernel with this distribution.
Example
The unit circle can be identified with the distribution $C$ given by
$$C(\phi) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\,d\theta.$$
The heat evolution of a temperature field $T_0$ on the unit circle is then given by $T(\bullet,t)=(T_0 C)*K_t,$ i.e.
$$T(x,y) = \int_0^{2\pi} T_0(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) \, K_t(x-\cos\theta,y-\sin\theta) \, d\theta.$$
